# Where does Magento store Pdf Invoices?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, invoice, pdf

Is there a table in the database or a folder where Magento (1.9 and 2.1) stores Pdf Invoices?

Comment: No PDF are generated on Fly as soon as user/admin requests it

Comment: But @VishwasBhatnagar user can use extension for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento doesn't store PDF files, it generates PDF on demand.
It keeps all the required data in different tables and compose the PDF based on configurations and PDF template.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the name of the events (admin panel and user panel) called when the pdf is shown? I want to create an observer and show another pdf.

Comment: You'll find pdf directory in model of sales module. There is a PHP file which renders the pdf, you can extend that renderer and customize the pdf as you want.

Comment: Thanks for updating knowledge. I also came to know about it by your answer.

Comment: ++1 from me for answer

Comment: @Arman It's a good solution. But I simply want to open a pdf file (that I generate before) saved in a folder. I was trying to override the method getPdf of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php but it doesn't work (at least in magento 2.1).

Comment: Then simply add a line before file is served to browser and save that object in a folder as well.

Comment: In Magento 1.9 I can do it overriding method getPdf of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php. But in Magento 2.1 I can't do it in the same way...

Comment: You can override the class in 2.1 as well using di.xml. The coding pattern is different but logic will remain same here.

Comment: Thanks. I did it.  
I solved overriding the method getPdf of the class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice. In the implemented method I loaded my pdf using: $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf ($pdfPath, null, true); (other stuff) return $pdf;

Answer (score -1):

These two extensions you can use

1 [Export PDF Magento](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pdf-export-for-reports.html)

2 [Mazento PDF Extension](http://www.magazento.com/english/magento-ext/magazento-extensions/pdf-export)

Comment: Any of the module doesn't export invoices which is requirement here.

Comment: Yes that generates reports. But I thought they might help. Thanks for updating knowledge